# Which attribute in Active Directory is used to store 'Outlook Anywhere' details?

Tags: active-directory, exchange, exchange-2007, outlook, outlook-anywhere

I'm using Active Directory and Exchange 2010. I want to know which LDAP attribute in Active Directory will be affected if I enable or disable 'Outlook Anywhere' feature.

Answer (score 2):

Outlook Anywhere/OWA "details" aren't stored in an Active Directory attribute.  They're fetched from an Exchange server with the CAS (Client Access Server) Role installed on it.  As to how the client discovers the Exchange CAS, [there's a technet blog about that](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2008/09/26/3406344.aspx).